# Java UDP Port 161 scan

Tags: java, sockets, udp, port

Port 161 is used by SNMP. I wrote a small peice of code to check if a device is running SNMP on this port.

```
public boolean isPortOpen(String ip, int port, int timeout) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);
        socket.close();
        logger.info(threadId, "Port is Open : " + ip + ":" + port );
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        logger.error(threadId, "isPortOpen : " + ip + ":" + port + "\t"+ ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

However to my surprise the **code always returns false for port 161** even though the box is running SNMP and other tools such as [PortQryV2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17148) return true for port 161. Can someone please help!! TIA

Comment: You are attempting to connect with TCP to port 161. That won't work if you're actually trying to find out if something is listening for UDP packets on port 161.

Comment: any suggestions on how to check for UDP?

Comment: There is no generic way to check if something is listening on an UDP port. You could perhaps send a valid SNMP request and see if you get an answer.